# In my silverlight application, I need to refresh an entity that I know has been changed in the database. How can I do this using RIA services?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

In my silverlight application, I need to refresh an entity that I know has been changed in the database. How can I do this using RIA services?

I am using an Entity Framework Domain Service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked into the [LoadBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.client.loadbehavior%28v=vs.91%29.aspx) usage in WCF RIA. You could use it to refresh the entities RIA quietly retains in its context. This blog [here](http://blog.falafel.com/blogs/10-08-12/WCF_RIA_Services_Default_Load_Behavior_Can_Be_Misleading.aspx) also might help.